# Wordpress Gallery shortcode in Single.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have exported the content from one Wordpress site to another. 
I would like to display the gallery images (attached to each post) from within the wordpress single.php template file.

I have added this to single.php to display gallery images associated with each post:

```
 <?php
    $gallery_shortcode = '[gallery id="' . intval( $post->post_parent ) . '"]';
    print apply_filters( 'the_content', $gallery_shortcode );
 ?>
```

However this is displaying all of the images within wordpress, and not only the images which are linked to each post?

Is my code possibly incorrect, or is it that the images are no longer linked to each post when it was imported from the other site?

This is the entire content of my 'single.php' file:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Seventeen
 * @since 1.0
 * @version 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>


<div class="wrap">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">



            <?php
                /* Start the Loop */
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );


                    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                    if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                        comments_template();
                    endif;


                    the_post_navigation( array(
                        'prev_text' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous Post', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span><span aria-hidden="true" class="nav-subtitle">' . __( 'Previous', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span> <span class="nav-title"><span class="nav-title-icon-wrapper">' . twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'arrow-left' ) ) . '</span>%title</span>',
                        'next_text' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next Post', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span><span aria-hidden="true" class="nav-subtitle">' . __( 'Next', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span> <span class="nav-title">%title<span class="nav-title-icon-wrapper">' . twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'arrow-right' ) ) . '</span></span>',
                    ) );

                endwhile; // End of the loop.
            ?>

<?php
    $gallery_shortcode = '[gallery id="' . intval( $post->post_parent ) . '"]';
    print apply_filters( 'the_content', $gallery_shortcode );
 ?>
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div><!-- .wrap -->

<?php get_footer();
```

Thank you

I tested my code by "attaching" an image manually to a post - it still brings up all of the images in Wordpress rather than just the one image I manually attached to my post?

Comment: I think ... the post not linked with posts ... how you import the data (1: Import DB, 2: tools=> Import)

Comment: @deemi I imported in sections with 1. tools=>import, - not sure if the DB itself was imported.  Is there a plugin I could possibly use for the export rather?

Comment: wordpress tools => imported always mis the images

Comment: I tested my code by "attaching" an image manually to a post - it still brings up all of the images in Wordpress rather than just the one image I manually attached to my post?